# Charts candle width changes when adding another series

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, candlestick-chart

I've got a candlestick chart showing prices with two series representing price and volume. This all works fine and displays as follows.

[image: Correctly Displayed]

The point width for these candles is set using `_stockSeries["PointWidth"] = "0.6";`

I then add a new series to the same chart area indicating points on the chart and the candle width changes to become very thin. I then have to set the `PointWidth` to ~15000 to get the candles a reasonable width. This number seems to bear no relation to anything on the chart as far as I can tell and is a lot larger than the original 0.6. Can anyone explain what's going on here?

[image]

The code used for adding the points is

```
        var genericPoints = new Series(name);

        if (style != MarkerStyle.None)
            genericPoints.MarkerStyle = style;

        genericPoints.ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastPoint;
        foreach (var price in points)
            genericPoints.Points.AddXY(price.TimeStamp, price.Value);

        _chart.Series.Add(genericPoints);
```

Comment: Sounds very strange. [PointWidth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456723.aspx) goes from 0f-2f, so your numbers make no sense. Did you test with other types than fastpoint? How many points do you have?

Comment: @TaW Yes, it seems to happen with all chart types. I've tried Point, Line and FastLine too. There are about 20 points I'm adding. If I add the series with no points then it has no effect on the candles. If I use `PixelPointWidth`, then the candles are not affected by adding another series.

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce. Do reset the PointWidth to a sensible value, i.e. below `1`. You may also want to try the `PixelPointWidth` cust.property instead, see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dc24f6e8-1a44-4680-b9e6-299da3c09219/setting-pointwidth-according-to-the-number-of-items-in-a-column-chart?forum=MSWinWebChart). Your x-values look, um a bit large. Sure they are correct?

Comment: @TaW `PixelPointWidth` works fine. (I mentioned that above). Do you know how I can get the width of the chart area? There's `ChartArea.Position`, but the width of that is zero, I assume because it's set to auto size. I'll try to create an SSCCE. The X values are ms epoch times - they are correct, just not elegant yet. It's a work in progress. :-)

Comment: You can get it by calling ToRectangleF on it or maybe by calling sth. like axisrescale before. In a hurry atm.. You may want the Innerplotposition. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+innerplotposition) for several posts of mine on it..

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, addressed with

```
    Private Sub chart_PrePaint(sender As Object, e As ChartPaintEventArgs) Handles chart.PrePaint
    Dim areasize As Double
    areasize = chart.Width * 0.6
    chart.Series("Candles")("PixelPointWidth") = areasize / (chart.Series("Candles").Points.Count)

    End Sub
```

Hope this helps